# AngularJS directive passing dynamic ui-sref

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router, coffeescript

I'm using the old AngularJS 1.5.11 in a large project and I'm trying to clean up my templates using directives.

I have an edit button directive in which I would like to pass through the ui-sref but when I do I get the error

```
Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '}' not a primary expression at column 6 of the expression [{id: }] starting at [}].
```

Here is my directive

```
editButton = ->

  return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    scope: {
      sref: "@"
    },
    template: '
    sref = {{sref}}
      <button id="edit-btn"
              class="mds__button -blue"
              ui-sref={{sref}}>
        <i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Edit
      </button>
    '
  }

angular
  .module('myApp')
  .directive('editButton', editButton)
```

And here is how I call it

```
<edit-button sref="job_edit({id: {{job.id}}})" />
```

In my template I display the sref and it's correctly printed out but the button doesn't like the ui-sref.

**Update**

I got it working but it would be nice to refactor this so I pass the job_edit({id: job.id}) attribute and it works.

Directive;

```
editButton = ->

  return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    scope: {
      model: "@"
      item: "="
    },
    template: '
      <button id="edit-btn"
              class="mds__button -blue"
              ui-sref="{{model}}_edit({id: item.id})">
        <i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Edit
      </button>
    '
  }

angular
  .module('myApp')
  .directive('editButton', editButton)
```

Calling it in my templates;

```
<edit-button model="job" item="job" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't make that `sref = {{sref}}` inside an Angularjs template.

When you declare `sref` on the `scope` object of the directive that means that your directive gets an isolated scope with `sref` property on it, with the value that was passed to the directive as an attribute.

This declaration has few possible values, such as, `@`, `=`, `&`.

1. `@` is used for an interpolation value, that means that whenever you pass a value to the attribute, you need pass some interpolation

```
<edit-button sref="{{somethingAvailableOnParentScope}}" />
```

2. `=` 2 way data binding, you need to pass some expression

```
<edit-button sref="somethingAvailableOnParentScope" />
```

3. `&` bind a function, used to pass a "pointer" to a function. (not relevant for our case)

To sum up, we want to pass the value of `job_edit` invokation to our directive, therefore we need to use `=`.

```
editButton = () => ({
    restrict: 'EA',
    scope: {
      sref: "="
    },
    template: '
      <button id="edit-btn"
              class="mds__button -blue"
              ui-sref="sref">
        <i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Edit
      </button>
    '
  });

angular
  .module('myApp')
  .directive('editButton', editButton)
```

And the usage will be something like that:

```
<edit-button sref="job_edit({id: job.id})" />
```

Comment: I was just using sref = {{sref}} to display the variable on the screen.

Comment: What do you get?